# Copy file among subdomain in php

Tags: php

I want to copy some files from a subdomain to another subdomain, but files are not being copied. Is there any option need to on in php.ini file or else?

Comment: Share the code you're using

Comment: copy('http://sample.domain.com/frontend/sample_file.pdf', 'http://sample-1.domain.com/frontend/sample_file.pdf');

Answer (score -1):

[from comments]

> ```
> copy('http://sample.domain.com/frontend/sample_file.pdf',
>      'http://sample-1.domain.com/frontend/sample_file.pdf');
> ```

You can not *write* via PHP’s [HTTP wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php). At least the second parameter needs to be a file system path here, not an HTTP URL.

(The first parameter can be an HTTP URL, if the configuration option `allow_url_fopen` is set to true.)